# Jquery mobile -page does not scroll

Tags: android, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

i'm developing app using intel XDK new environment by using jquery mobile.
here is my code for a form for submitting data.

```
      <div data-role="content">
        <form method="post"  action="http://testwebpage.php">

          <div data-role="fieldcontain">

            <label class="formLabel" style="width: 250px;">
              <span class="formTitle">First Name:</span>
              <input type="text" name="fname1" placeholder="Type first name here..." data-="" mini="true" data-inline="true" value="">
            </label>
          </div>
          <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label class="formLabel" style="width: 250px;">
              <span class="formTitle">Last Name:</span>
              <input type="text" name="lname1" placeholder="Type first name here..." data-="" mini="true" data-inline="true" value="">
            </label>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Emulator shows the form correctly (it can scroll down without entering any data to fields)But when i test it on the real device (xperial L) it does not scroll down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to fix this error add this line

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```

to the head